# append ndarrays with the same shape

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I have this 2 objects:

```
a.shape
(10000, 32, 32, 3)
b.shape
(50000, 32, 32, 3)
```

I want to concatenate the elements of a to b to create one array with all elements from both arrays.

how can I do it?

Thanks

Comment: Try numpy.concatenate() if a simple concatenation is required.

Comment: Define add operation when shapes are different. It is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: What do you mean by "add"? Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: @TD_Asker Thats it, thanks

Comment: I've added a full answer for completeness. I think the key terminology challenge in your question is distinguishing between 'add' (a mathematical operator) and 'concatenate' (this should now be edited to reflect correct terminology).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a simple concatentation is required, use `numpy.concatenate`. See [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html).

```
import numpy as np

a = np.ones((10000, 32, 32, 3))
b = np.ones((50000, 32, 32, 3))

c = np.concatenate((a, b))
print(c.shape)

>>> (60000, 32, 32, 3)
```